# HTML Editor for Windows Mobile Smartphone

Tags: html

Are there any HTML editors for windows mobile smartphones with which I can create HTML on my smartphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two editors that you can use but, of course, you can find a lot of alternative.

- [Integrated HTML Editor 1.0](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/File-editor/Integrated-HTML-Editor-Pocket-PC-15786.shtml)
- [Eazy Html Editor 1.1](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/File-editor/Eazy-Html-Editor-18796.shtml)

Comment: I meant an IDE for Windows Mobile, sorry :) I want to create html files on my smartphone.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I hope the question is better now.

Comment: Thank you! Are pocket pcs and smartphones the same? These two editors seem to be a bit older.

Comment: @cberg They are what you need ;) The problem that they're a little bit older it's because Windows Mobile is an older O.S.